# Explaining the Biba Model with an example

Tags: security, model

I have read about the Ba LaPadula (BLP) model of computer security and I managed to understand how it achieves confidentiality through an [example](https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/14ipbp/can_you_explain_the_belllapadula_model_to_someone/)
Can someone explain for me the Biba Model with an example from an organization of any choice.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for my Information Security class. My group used the military example from [the Wikipedia article:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biba_Model)

- if a general wants to change a mission that's in progress, then he has the right to do that. That data has a high level of integrity. Therefore, everyone below him has permission to trust that information.
- if a private sends a message about a change in the mission, then that data is not to be trusted. It has a low level of integrity. Therefore, no one above him has permission to trust that information.